# Could an insect-winged humanoid keep its private parts covered?

Tags: clothing, insectoid, winged-humans

Could a fairy (which is like a 10cm tall human with an insect-like abdomen attached to the coccyx region of the hips, which expands and contracts to breathe like a human chest, and that also have wings and a set of pterothoracic nota which replace the thoracic spine and the rear part of the ribcage, which is also flexible to allow flight), cover its breasts, crotch/pelvis, and the end of its insect-abdomen using fabric, without restricting the wearer too much and avoiding the mentioned areas slipping out?

Comment: Insect femminism  "free the nipple"

Comment: this is really up to you and depends on the anatomy of your creature. things like breast and crotch have no meaning for insects.

Comment: I have explained their anatomy. If there is too little information, please tell me what you need to know about them

Comment: Why would an insectoid fairy need to do such a weird thing in the first place? This is the kind of thing that needs to be clarified.

Comment: More appropriately, how does it protect it's modesty if the covering falls off? I have a really interesting vision of an ant trying to 'cover up' bu putting its 'hands' in front of its 'personal parts' and trying to run away.

Comment: Just one word: spandex.

Comment: @John: While I agree with you that it depends on the specific anatomy, an insectoid creature does have a breast-analogous region (the forward/under side of the thorax) and depending on ones definition of "crotch", it either comprises the multiple locations where the insect's legs meet its body or the regions around its reproductive orifaces. As such, saying that these terms have "no meaning" for insects is a bit strong, in my opinion.

Comment: Inspired by landing gears, they are retractable to reduce drag...

Comment: This doesn't seem that different from designing clothing for humans with feathered wings - for which you can refer to basically any artistic interpretation of angels as humans with feathered wings.  And, honestly, you could also refer to any artistic interpretation of clothed fairies as well.  This is really a solved problem.

Comment: Feathered wings do not encompass the entirety of the chest. And most depictions of clothed fairies do not have functional insectoid wings

Comment: Also, there are no depictions of fairies with breathing abdomens

Comment: Just Google Image search Tinkerbell, only the most widely recognized fairy in the world.  Okay, so she's got human-like legs, but other than that, the outfit does exactly what you're asking for.  Covers her up in the most G-rated family-friendly way you possibly can, and also leaves her back exposed so the wings are free.

Comment: Tinkerbell has neither an insect-like abdomen, nor functional neopteran wings

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Tinkerbell is more of an exercise in upskirting.  We never get an eyeful, but she regularly hovers above other characters' eyelines, and that skirt does not cover very much.  So whilst we don't know what (if any) underwear or sexual characteristics she has under there, all other characters certainly would!

Comment: "Insect-like wings which attach to the entire length of the thoracic spine" - that doesn't sound very insect-like. Don't most insect wings just attach at a small "shoulder" region?

Comment: Neopteran wings attach to the back of the mesothorax and metathorax between the nota and pleura

Comment: "This is really a solved problem." - 'Why an insectoid does such a weird thing is the kind of thing that needs to be clarified" - y'all need to choose which close reason fits your offended sensibilities better. Seems pretty clear to me. The DV button is underneath the UV button. A close vote should link to the dupe that we're all too lazy to find.

Comment: Where does it keep its crotch. It would really help if you were to provide an illustration with labels, seriously.

Comment: The crotch is where it would be on a human, as this creature is a human except for the traits outlined above

Comment: When you say where it would be on a human, do you mean at the distal end of the abdomen where the hips are attached? Or is the abdomen sticking out the back with the hips attached to the thorax? A sketch (rough would be fine) would help. Not voting to reopen yet until we understand what you're after.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start with underwear and build out from there.

Ideas for 'chest' support/covering:

1) A stretchy 'bra' that loops around the arms, pulling itself tight enough to stay in place.

2) An ordinary 'bra' that loops around the arms and kept on by a string from the back of the shoulders across the front of the neck, maybe in a knot or tied to a metal ring with an optional third string up from the center chest.

3) A 'bra' that loops around the head, neck, and shoulders like above, held together by buttons/zipper/ties down the center chest.

Ideas for crotch support/covering:

1) Stretchy fabric like any modern underwear, with gaps for the wist, thorax, and each leg. (They'd have to exhale and hold their breath while squeezing it on, but I think that'd work.)

2) A fabric ribbon like a scarf wrapped loosely around the crotch area until sufficiently covered, then tied off or tucked in.

3) A loincloth, tied above the thorax (might be uncomfortable if too tight, but necklaces aren't rare).

The upper torso I'm not sure there's any way to fully clothe. Sleeves can be supported with string across the front, and the strategies above can be doubled up, with more fabric.

Lower torso:

1) A piece for the upper and rear thorax, which attaches by zipper/stiches/buttons/ties, etc. to one for the lower thorax and legs, and a belt.

2) Pants that wrap around the thorax to button, strap, or tie along the sides or top, pulled up by a string or belt around the thorax connection in turn connected to a loop supporting the front of the pants

Gloves, shoes, and headwear are as for a human, but nothing wide-brimmed that extends backward would stick perminantly.

The jumpsuit: a single piece of fabric (or whatever) with sleeves on as per chest strat 1, 2, or 3, goes into a narrow strip down the center of the stomach, [edit: or a kind of hourglass or X-shape narrowest in the center torso] (keeps it out of the way of the wings when the spine turns) to the top of the pants, lower body as per strat 1 or 2.

All of the above work for either gender, assuming you went with the popular default, though I imagine only one matters for the character(s) you're thinking of, hence 'chest.'

Any of that helpful?

Answer (score 32):

**Trivial Answer:**  "Private parts" are a cultural construct.  Define your culture such that no parts of these fairies are considered "private".

**Obvious Answer:**  There are a number of "backless" one-piece swimwear designs for real-world human women, some of which have more-or-less arbitrarily low coverage of the wearer's back, leaving the entire thoracic spine uncovered and covering only some portion of the lumbar spine.  Use the same basic design, with the back cut low enough to avoid the base of the wings.

**Anatomical Answer:**  You're describing your fairies as having highly-insectoid anatomy (not just wings, but also an expandable thorax), so why would they have human-like sexual anatomy or secondary sexual characteristics, rather than insectoid sexual anatomy?

**Adhesive Answer:**  Performers in various adult-oriented industries make use of adhesive pasties to conceal their nipples.  The same concept could be employed here, gluing patches to the fairy's body to provide any necessary covering without interfering with other parts of their body.

**Answer Pulled from Current Events:**  There are a lot of people currently wearing face-covering masks which hook behind their ears rather than wrapping around the backs of their heads.  Similarly, you could use body coverings which hook behind the limbs rather than wrapping around the back of the body.

Comment: Insect anatomy is rather similar to human anatomy minus the breasts. Well, that, and that the human penis doesn't have tiny claws to grab onto the female reproductive organs. I do like the idea nevertheless - no nipples, no problem.

Answer (score 10):

apron maybe? or this traditional chinese underwear from: https://www.thoughtco.com/chinese-clothing-dudou-687371

[image]

from:https://local-moda.blogspot.com/2014/10/dudou-artistic-underwear-of-medieval.html

[image]

At least from what I have read it doesn’t seems like the wing expands from or is attached to the waist or leg (but correct me if I am wrong) so I think normal pants wouldn’t be a problem to wear.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a human-like in terms of physical frame and location of sexual organs or chartists, is this covering necessary in terms of culture or climate?

If it's to simply cover them for more cultural reasons, then they probably shouldn't be looking at a cloth or wrap-like attire. Wrap like attires is something that wraps around the frame of the body, like a dress.

- Perhaps something that physically ***sticks*** on over anyparts like a
  glued-on amour plating or plans/fabric brushed into the front flesh with a
  type of tree sap could give the appearance of cloth wrapped around. 
  This option would cover but not hinder the placement of wings or movement
- Bodypaint (waterproof and non) would work to obscure physical features.
- Body hair/ fur could be another thing that could be used to obscure physical features, though this would no doubt be more in the climate-based evolution

Comment: Stick-on clothing would be hard to remove quickly, and the adhesive would wear down

Comment: would body modifications such as pieces be compatible? Say, one had a few specific rods graphed into the skin/body, use a lightweight fabric to catch onto said rod to act as an anchor; the only permanent things that wouldn't need to be removed are the rods, everything else could be removed and released quickly

Comment: Why does the clothing need to be removed quickly? A solvent could be used to dissolve the glue.

Can you draw a picture of what this bug person looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not. This depends entirely on your species, but a lot of insects have really, really huge ovipositors that can be longer than the entire species' body put together.

[image]
[image]

Of course the irony of this from our mammal-centric point of view is that these are *females*, not males. In fact, the stingers of wasps and bees are modified genitalia. These structures are often very hard and cannot be easily manipulated or folded up. I have a really, really hard time seeing how any clothing could preserve any sort of modesty in these kinds of organisms.

Some insects lack ovipositors, but many have additional organs that stick out such as sensillae, valvulae, or paraprocts that would be harder to cover up than a simple genital duct or something like a mammalian penis. Worse is that most insects have cerci of some kind sticking out at the terminal end of their abdomen (i.e., those things sticking out of the butts of crickets), and these are very sensitive and used by the insect to help sense the world, and thus it would be very uncomfortable to keep them bundled up under clothing. It would be the equivalent of wearing clothing that folds your ears funny.